# Could a ion thruster work in atmosphere with enough energy?

Tags: physics, spaceships, energy, astrophysics

Well, some days ago I watched a video talking about the Halo transport ship "Pelican", which uses nuclear fusion turbines (don't worry, this question isn't about Halo).
And technically, nuclear fission or fusion are ion thrusters, since they expel ionised atoms and stuff like that (I may be wrong).

However, ion thrusters, the ones we have today, releases a little of energy, but for longer periods of time. Therefore, if I insert enough energy in that, it could work like the other types of engine? How inefficient it would be?

Comment: Ion thrusters have a long history of use in atmosphere, you can make one yourself at home, it's called a lifter, so yes, Ion thrusters work in atmosphere, [here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HL1tiWEDls), but I don't think it's what you thought you meant

Comment: Anything works with enough energy.

Comment: @DKNguyen - Increasing the energy may increase the mass of the rocket in such a way that the net force/mass decreases or stays constant--and unless you can get force/mass up to 9.8 m/s^2 you won't be able to get off the ground. All existing ion drives have much lower force/mass, though it's conceivable that the type of plasma thruster discussed [here](https://www.centauri-dreams.org/2021/02/03/magnetic-reconnection-in-new-thruster-concept/) could generate enough thrust, see my comments on [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/49970/12273) from the space stack exchange.

Comment: @Hypnosifl When the OP says "if I insert enough energy into that" I am interpreting that as "magically insert enough energy in that"

Comment: It seems like if you have something very hot, and atmosphere, you can propel yourself by throwing hot atmosphere behind you more easily than you could throwing ions behind you.

Comment: If you are in the atmosphere then you are surrounded by easily accessible and freely available reaction mass and can use plain old jet engines. Ion thrusters are interesting when you are *not* surrounded by easily accessible and freely available reaction mass.

Comment: Idk why the downvotes, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion-propelled_aircraft , so as there are examples of working models of that kind. Trust will be higher than in space, design will be different, as u have air around, each ion collides with those and it lowers ISP but increases force

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ion engine" is a slightly ill-defined concept. In the real world, the term is used to describe electric propulsion systems... some reaction mass is ionised, and then accelerated using electrostatic or electromagnetic forces.

In theory, you could indeed use an engine of this type to fly around in an atmosphere, but in practise to run into a bunch of serious problems.

The first is thrust-to-weight ratios. These tend to be *low*, because all that power handling kit and field generating gear is heavy. In space this doesn't matter quite so much, but obviously when you're not in orbit if you can't generate enough thrust you won't be going anywhere.

The second is the power requirement, and this is *big*. There's a tradeoff to be made between having high exhaust velocities and therefore being very efficient when it comes to propellant usage, and high thrust. If you want high thrust, you need a *lot* of power. The [DS4G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-Stage_4-Grid) prototype thruster uses 250kW to generate 2.5N of thrust... that means it would need 15 *gigawatts* of power to match the thrust of an Airbus A321.

[Ionocraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion-propelled_aircraft) such as the one Pelinore linked, use a stream of ions to push a larger but slower mass of air. This gives them much more thrust for a given amount of power, but you can't easily have an ionocraft that can fly into space without having to carry a second set of vacuum-capable engines (or without some  very clever engineering). Prototype ionocraft actually exist with onboard power, such as the [MIT EAD](https://news.mit.edu/2018/first-ionic-wind-plane-no-moving-parts-1121) which have managed to sustain powered flight for a few metres. Maybe in the future with the invention of more powerful and lightweight electrical generators, more capable craft of this type could be made. You might need to invent fusion first, though.

---

> nuclear fusion turbines (don't worry, this question isn't about Halo).

Did you know, nuclear turbines have actually been built in the past? Behold, the HTRE-3 nuclear gas turbine.

[image: HTRE-3 nuclear gas turbine]

Instead of using an exothermic chemical reaction to heat gas and drive the turbine, it uses reactor heat. No aircraft ever used this kind of engine to fly, but it was entirely practical even back in the 60s. In your scifi future it should be easy!

> And technically, nuclear fission or fusion are ion thrusters, since they expel ionised atoms and stuff like that (I may be wrong).

Nuclear *thermal* engines don't spit out ions or plasma, and those kind of engines a) have been successfully operated in the past and b) could in fact manage to generate enough thrust to lift their own weight. Fusion designs like Bussard's [Quiet Electric Dischard](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.507.5846&rep=rep1&type=pdf) engine use ions to heat propellant, but the propellant will just come out as hot non-ionised gas if you want to generate enough thrust to take off from a planet.

So, yeah. Ion engines, not great in an atmosphere. Nuclear engines: potentially useful, probably not ion engines.

Comment: Now I'm kinda curious, do you think this nuclear power would be useful and accepted in commercial aircraft instead of using regular engines? (I don't think this question is worth a post tho).

Comment: @NetoAnanias I don't think that _fission_ reactors could ever be used in commercial aircraft... the fallout from an accident (both political and radiological) would be too serious for anyone to accept now. Maybe in an alternative 1960s it could have been pulled off. If aneutronic fusion becomes a practical reality though... well, that's a different matter, and would be an absolute game-changer for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the ship concerned but if it using 'fusion turbines' then that probably (in a hard SF setting) indicates it is using a nuclear fusion power plant to generate power/heat for air breathing turbine engines in order to provide propulsion for *atmospheric travel*. I presume it would then 'switch' over to on board reaction mass for powered flight in space.

Designs for nuclear fission powered air breathing jets were worked on during the Cold War.  Regardless of which 'nuclear' option you go with the basic principal is the same. Air inlets at the front of the ship direct cold atmospheric gases into contact with super hot plasma from the fusion/fission reactor. The air is super-heated explosively  and forced out the rear of the jet engine generating thrust and turning the turbine blades which then draw in more 'cold' air through the inlets. The fusion reaction replaces the jet fuel (usually kerosene) carried by normal jets.

In the fission designs cold air comes into contact with the a super-critical/super hot fission core.

Of the two a 'fusion' jet would much more preferable even if also much more complex. This is because all the 'fission' designs resulted in massive amounts of radioactive  bi products being shot out the back with the exhaust gasses which would be a big downer for anyone under the flight path.

As far as Ion drives go I don't think it would work the power to thrust ration is too low. However look up **Plasma Dives** they are an intermediate step on the road to true fusion and might be a  suitable substitute. Both Ion and plasma drives use the principals of elect-magnetism to accelerate particles and produce thrust. Plasma drives are more power intensive but in theory will also produce more thrust and hot plasma could, I suppose be diverted in the same manner as fusion plasma to produce thrust in an air breathing engine.

Still wouldn't want to be driving behind one as it took off in an airport service van though.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, I think would be that ion thrusters are a TYPE of electric thrusters, electric thrusters being a conveying of energy to reaction mass through electricity, either directly like an ion thruster, or indirectly like a microwave cavity thruster, and so the short answer would be yes, but it would no longer be an ion thruster but rather another form of propulsion, with the primary propellant being ionized through electric mechanisms.

Apologies for the poor citing format

[Link to the atomic rocket page](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist.php)

Comment: \[ text \]( link ) will do the trick, without spaces at beginning and end of content in brackets